# Can oracle dbca template be used cross versions

Tags: oracle

If you have a dbca template to create a database for version 12.1, will it also work for creating a database on 12.2 binaries?

Will it also work for creating a database on 11g binaries?

Comment: I have a set_oracle_env.sh script. When I want to set the Oracle environment variables i source it with the sid name. As in ". /home/oracle/scripts/bin/set_oracle_env.sh mysid". If you do that there should be no reason to use a different Oracle home to use the dbca. Set your environment to point to the version of Oracle that you want and run the dbca from that Oracle home.

Answer (score 0):

The information in templates includes database options, initialization parameters, and storage attributes. I use scripts instead, but from what I can see in $ORACLE_HOME/assistants/dbca/templates they are XML files which should translate to the creation of your CREATE DATABASE statement as well as init.ora which hasn't changed between 12.1 and 12.2 apart from a few deprecated parameters.

I would imagine it's not downward compatible to 11g, but there's no harm in trying?